# Remove Quotes from Text Fields

Tags: templating, replace, escaping

My client needs to input apostrophes in text fields for staff names, such as ’ or just the plain ' and as you can imagine, it is causing issues.

I have tried this `replace({'\'',''})` and this `replace({'\&rsquo;',''})` but to no success. Thoughts?

Comment: Can you be more specific describing the problem, isral? Plain Text fields should handle straight or curly apostrophes just fine without any special handling, and I believe Rich Text fields should be no different. I'm struggling to understand why the client inputting them is a problem _and_ why you're attempting to remove them at the template level.

Comment: Hi, @MattStein. i am removing them at the template level because i use thise text fields to create IDs which are targeted in JS/jQ. For example, if the field has "First L'ast" then JS won't be able to get the IDs because they become something like `data-target="firstl'ast"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it happens, this solved my issue: `{{ personfirstandlastname|replace({'\'':''}) }}`

**EDIT**

To clarify, this isn't a valid Twig object:

```
{'\'',''}
```

... while this is:

```
{'\'':''}
```

Comment: Wasn't that what you described specifically _not_ working in your question? _edit: nevermind, I see the `,` became a `:`_

Comment: @MattStein i will be increasing text sizes in my browser.